# mongs failed to findone when collection is under sharding migration

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection which enabled sharding on 2 replica sets, `rs01` and `rs02`.
I added a new replica set `rs03`, it started to migrating chunks to `rs03` *slowly*(it only migrated about 300 chunks in 4 days...)

It is weird that I do a `find().limit(1)` or `findOne()` on the collection on mongos, it hung there without response.(I need ctrl-c to escape the mongo shell on mongos).

How to check anything wrong that makes the query stuck?
Because the mongo.log on the `rs01` is filled with migration actions that I cannot find useful message that make the `findOne()` query stuck.

Moreover, I tried findOne() on the sharded collection on `rs01`, `rs02`, `rs03` ,all can return document. Only hung on mongos.

Below is message from mongos by `db.locks.find( { _id : "balancer" } ).pretty()`

```
mongos> db.locks.find( { _id : "balancer" } ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "balancer",
    "state" : 2,
    "who" : "mongos30-02:27017:1459106195:1804289383:Balancer:846930886",
    "ts" : ObjectId("5784b2b42e0cc50683dc622e"),
    "process" : "mongos30-02:27017:1459106195:1804289383",
    "when" : ISODate("2016-07-12T09:04:52.713Z"),
    "why" : "doing balance round"
}
```

Update: I tried adding a balancer schedule at midnight. the balancer stopped now. Even the migration thread stopped, It still failed to `findOne()` on mongos. but worked on each primary node.

I got log from mongos when I issue findOne() command as below:

```
2016-07-13T14:15:06.118+0800 I SHARDING [LockPinger] cluster mongocfg30-01:27019,mongocfg30-02:27019,mongocfg30-03:27019 pinged successfully at Wed Jul 13 14:15:05 2016 by distributed lock pinger 'mongocfg30-01:27019,mongocfg30-02:27019,mongocfg30-03:27019/mongos30-01:27017:1459049395:1804289383', sleeping for 30000ms
```

The cluster map is as below(some mongo version are not the same)
All node OS is ubuntu 14.04 kvm, where all mongod have 20G RAM.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: by the way, if I add filter _id to a specific id object on find(), mongos can return the record.

Comment: Also, I tried findOne() on `rs01`, `rs02`, `rs03` all can return document. Only hung on mongos

Comment: In general migration is a background activity that does not block queries so there must be other factors in play if you can query from all shard replica sets but not via `mongos`. Your earlier question on chunk migration (http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/143265/9345) suggests you've added a new shard `rs03` and there may be a significant amount of migrations happening (perhaps overwhelming your server resources). Can you provide some more details: what specific version of MongoDB server and O/S are you using (and if MongoDB 3.0.x+, what storage engine and file system)?

Comment: Were you using the same read preference when querying via `mongos` vs the shards directly (i.e. reading from primary)? Are all components of your cluster (`mongos` and `mongod`) using identical MongoDB versions? Also, how many `mongos` do you have? Have you checked the `mongos` logs for any further information that might correlate with your query blocking?

Comment: Hi, @Stennie, Yes, I use `db.mycollect.findOne()` on primaries and mongos.I've updated more detailed arch info. I need to check the mongos log   further, Although I `tail -f /var/log/mongo/mongos.log | grep mycollect` when I use `db.mycollect.findOne()`, I got no info.

Comment: @Stennie, I found a weird thing that if I use GUI client `robomongo`, connected into mongs, I can easily `findOne()` with result. However, I use mongos mongo shell or python mongo driver both hung on `findOne()`

Comment: Definitely not sounding like a familiar problem yet. I expected you'd have more information in the `mongos` log. Rather than grepping for the query can you provide a gist/pastebin with more of the log? One thought is that you may be running into low ulimits (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/), but that is usually evident in logs as well as a peak number of connections. It's also interesting that you see different behaviour in Robomongo; what specific version are you using? Is your screenshot from Cloud Manager or Ops Manager?

Comment: Can you also confirm the storage engine you are using, the file system, and the `version()` reported in your `mongo` shell as well as Robomongo? Unrelated to this issue, but I would also strongly recommend upgrading your `rs02` nodes to 3.0.12 as there have been some critical bug fixes. For 3.0.9 in particular, see: [SERVER-23425](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23425); for all the changes see [MongoDB 3.0 changelog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-changelog/).

Comment: @stennie, here are some operations I just tried. https://gist.github.com/changsijay/e5ecb7255bdb1d8b215aa7d4673a1a35

Comment: @stennie, I also tried to connect mongos on another ubuntu with latest mongo3.0 shell(3.0.12), still hung on findOne().  BTW, findOne() only failed on 2 sharding collections, I can do normal queries on other collections.

Comment: yes, the screenshot is from mongo opsmanager.

Comment: Today, I found that when I query the sharding collection using mongo shell, it pop up a opid in rs01's primary which "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN", for a long time and the query hung. if I use robomongo client, it won't have the situation.

Comment: Thanks for providing more info .. unfortunately I still don't see any obvious clue to the issue (particularly why it might work from a tool but not the `mongo` shell. Your ulimits appear to be default on `mongos` and `rs01`; did you restart the processes after increasing the ulimits? You can check the limit for a process with `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`. However, if limits were problematic you should messages in the logs about connections being refused or see the connection chart flatline at around 819 connections (80% of the default 1024 limit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42517/discussion-between-stennie-and-csj).

Comment: Have you @CSJ solved this? I have the same issue.